# How to check firmware version in solaris?

Tags: solaris, hardware

I have searched in /usr/platform/sun4u/sbin path. But not sure how to get the firmware version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which firmware are you talking about?

If it is the OBP version that you're looking for, `prtdiag -v` will help you in most cases:

```
System PROM revisions:
----------------------
OBP 4.16.1 2004/09/03 04:22 Sun Fire V210/V240,Netra 240
OBDIAG 4.16.1 2004/09/03 04:23
```

The output of `prtconf -pv` may also have relevant sections:

```
Node 0xf002ce38
    version: 'OBP 4.16.1 2004/09/03 04:22'
    model:  'SUNW,4.16.1'
    aligned-allocator:  
    relative-addressing:  
    name:  'openprom'

Node 0xf0094d50
    sunw,location:  'U55'
    model:  'SUNW,254-0078'
    version: 'OBP 4.16.1 2004/09/03 04:22 Sun Fire V210/V240,Netra 240' + 'OBDIAG 4.16.1 2004/09/03 04:23  ' + 'POST 4.16.1 2004/09/03 11:38'
    name:  'flashprom'
    compatible: 'isa-flashprom'
```

Comment: Yes its OBP version.... thanks...  found it...                                           /usr/platform/sun4u/sbin/prtdiag –v | grep –i obp